# hash password stored as BSON BinData Type

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, bson

I have this script, which is a temporal method for adding users to a mongo database.

The operation procedes normally, but the hash generated for the password, is being stored as [BSON Binary Data (a.k.a BinData)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import bcrypt
from getpass import getpass
from pymongo import MongoClient

def connect():
    db_user = "mongo"
    db_pass = "mongo"
    db_addr = "127.0.0.1:27017"
    uri = "mongodb://{0}:{1}@{2}".format(db_user,db_pass,db_addr)
    client = MongoClient(uri,serverSelectionTimeoutMS=6000)
    return client

try:
    user_data = {}
    user_data["Name"]     = input("Full Name:  ")
    user_data["Sector"]   = input("Sector:     ")
    user_data["Email"]    = input("Email:      ")
    user_data["Username"] = input("Username:   ")
    password = getpass(prompt="Password:  ").encode('utf-8')
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
    pass_hash = bcrypt.hashpw(password, salt)
    user_data["Password"] = pass_hash
    client = connect()
    db = client.companydb
    collection = db.Authentication
    result = collection.insert_one(user_data)
    print("Done!")
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception:",e)
```

**MongoDB**

```
> db.Authentication.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1d9cf8e6023f20d3b11bf3"),
    "Name" : "My Full Name",
    "Password" : BinData(0,"JDJiJDEyJDR0RzFwRkNjaE1HdlExd0kuRXgyLk91U09yQWZYTWxZL2pZbUVod3N2NGhRR05XUXIyNDRh"),
    "Username" : "ivanleoncz",
    "Email" : "mymail@post.com",
    "Sector" : "IT"
}
```

I would like to understand:

- Why the hashed password is being stored as BSON BinData?
- Can I avoid this situation? If it is possible, how?
- Is there any difference between:

  > storing a dict directly **X** `insert_one({"Username":var_name,"Password":var_hash})`?

Comment: Why do you dislike saving the password verifier in binary? Futher `"JDJiJDEyJDR0RzFwRkNjaE1HdlExd0kuRXgyLk91U09yQWZYTWxZL2pZbUVod3N2NGhRR05XUXIyNDRh"` is Base64 encoded ACSII text, not binary, the encoded ASCII: `"$2b$12$4tG1pFCchMGvQ1wI.Ex2.OuSOrAfXMlY/jYmEhwsv4hQGNWQr244a"`.

Comment: It's not that I dislike and I didn't mentioned this. But, is it necessary to have the password hash in such format? I'd like to have the password hash as it is, but I'm open to understand why BinData format is ok, for example.

Comment: Ok. Could you elaborate this comment into an answer (formatting the idea)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the hashed password is being stored as BSON BinData?

This is because `bcrypt.hashpw()` returns `bytes` data type. For example:

```
b'$2b$12$bvjnkItDoYvw.GUwBeVuwOuIxIQ5hUIx.ECovNrnYc1kgSP/kruXu'
```

Also in PyMongo (Python 3) bytes will be encoded to [bson.binary.Binary()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/binary.html#bson.binary.Binary) and vice versa.

> Can I avoid this situation? If it is possible, how?

If you're intending to store the hash in string in MongoDB, you could decode the hash when storing in the dictionary. i.e.

```
user_data["Password"] = pass_hash.decode("utf-8")

# When checking later you would have to encode it back to bytes.
bcrypt.checkpw(b"mysecretpassword", user_data["Password"].encode("utf-8"))
```

As mentioned in the comment, in regards to just storing the password and restoring the password to authenticate later on, you can just keep it as binary (unless your use case requires it)

This is because when the document is retrieved back from MongoDB, in Python 3 instances of bson.Binary will be decoded directly back to bytes. You can test this by retrieving the document back using [find()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find)

> Is there any difference between: storing a dict directly vs insert_one

As you can see from the answer, this is a combination behaviour of `bcrypt.hashpw()` and `insert_one()`.

Comment: I was making some tests and I realized that "binary will be decoded directly to bytes", indeed. Thank you very much, dude. Very complete answer :)! Regards.

Comment: this is a great answer and a breakdown.  THANKS!